# How do you enable logging in Jasper Server 5.6?

Tags: java, tomcat, jasper-reports, jasperserver

According to [this article](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-installation-guide-community-edition/v60/jasperreports-0), the JasperServer log file should be `/var/lib/tomcat/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/logs/jasperserver.log`. I believe I have configured logging correctly (`/var/lib/tomcat/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/log4j.properties`) with the following relevant lines.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, fileout
log4j.appender.fileout.File=${jasperserver.root}/WEB-INF/logs/jasperserver.log
```

The purpose of enabling logging is so that I can more easily debug errors (e.g., SQL permission issues). Currently, our web application will throw an exception if JasperServer returns an HTTP `500 Internal Server Error`, but beyond that, there's no way to tell why the report failed to run.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

**UPDATE:** I know that the logging is not working because the file `/var/lib/tomcat/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/logs/jasperserver.log` does not exist on the filesystem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain in sufficient detail how it is that you know that logging is *not*, in fact, working; it probably seems pretty obvious, but just the same. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: Try using a fully-qualified path? Also, if the web application isn't starting, perhaps the logging framework isn't starting either? This may not be a problem with log4j configuration, but something that happens well before log4j comes up.

Answer (score 0):

If the all problem is only in non-existing the file "jasperserver.log" as you wrote... try to create it `touch /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/logs/jasperserver.log`

I am afraid that is not so simple. Ensure that user, under who jasper is running, has rights to the logs directory.

I would probably try to set logging through the jasper web administration. This worked for us.

Hope this help